# Error when creating new project in Android

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

This is the error I receive when creating a new project, Any suggestions on how to resolve it?

> Failed to open zip file. Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt
>   (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.) Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires
>   network)

Answer (score 0):

- first, you need to open your ternminal
- Second, you copy this code parse it in terminal: rm -Rf ~/.gradle
- then press enter
- Then you re-opend android studio and import your project again and it should work